# Nightwatch .waitForElementVisible('#primary-btn') warning : WaitForElement found 2 elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch with chrome driver for UI-Testing. I have come across an issue when trying to click on 'primary-btn' in the web-page. First the waitForElement returns a warning "Warn: WaitForElement found 2 elements for selector "#primary-btn". Only the first one will be checked" and the subsequent .click('#primary-btn') does not yield the desired result.

I checked the web-page to see if actually there are 2 elements with the name "#primary-btn" using document.getElementById('primary-btn'). However the function listed only 1 element with id 'primary-btn'

I am not sure why this happens. Does nightwatch support wait for animation to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[id='primary-btn']:nth-child(1)")
```

In nightwatch :

```
browser.waitForElementPresent("div[id='primary-btn']:nth-child(1)")
```

Comment: how to write this in nightwatch js ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have 2 elements in you page with an identical id. While the standard impose a unique name, it is not enforced in the browser. You can verify it by executing this command in your browser:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id='primary-btn']")
```

Or:

```
$x("//*[@id='primary-btn']")
```

So to get the expected element, you need to extend your selector with another condition. It could be for example:

```
'#container-id #primary-btn'
```

Comment: when i run the command  document.querySelectorAll("[id='primary-btn']")  i get the following result                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <div class="text-right header-last-col link-active" id="primary-btn">Next</div>

Comment: The container was probably cloned at some point for the animation and then deleted, while would explain the duplicated id.